# Need advices on Creational pattern (Builder)

Tags: php, design-patterns, builder

For my first post on Stackoverflow, I'd like ask for some advices about which pattern I should use (and how to use it properly) in order to structure my program.

(Don't hesitate to ask me precisions, English is not my mother tongue)

The program I'm developping is about assembling several forms information (information about an advertising campaign), the structure should be :

- formats of ad banners, with attributes like size, format name, ...
- models (optional) if several types of advertised products exist, containing formats
- districts (optional) if the campaign has several districts (area of advertising), containing formats (and eventually models if specified)
- publishers, which regroup formats (by district/model if specified)

To recap, I should have these 4 possible associations :

- **Publishers/Formats,**
- **Publishers/Models/Formats,**
- **Publishers/Districts/Formats,**
- **Publishers/Districts/Models/Formats**

My thoughts guided me towards the Builder pattern, due to the several possibilities of associations, but I'm not familiar with this one and I'm not sure about how to implement it.

Should my ConcreteBuilders be the 4 possible associations (like FormatBuilder for Publishers/Formats or DistrictModeleBuilder for Publishers/Districts/Models/Formats) and my Products be Format, Model, District, Publisher?

Does the Director class represent the form or does the form belong to the Client?

Thank you in advance for the enlightenments!

Comment: The Director is composed of a Builder. It is responsible for implementing the assembly process of the Product by calling buildPart() methods on the Builder. The Builder defines the individual steps that can be used to assemble the Product. It defines what is legal when constructing the Product so that when the final Product is retrueved it has a valid state. For example, you may not be able to buildPartB() without first having buildPartA(). The Builder is responsible for the state of the Product being valid when calling  builder.getResult()

Comment: For your specific deisng: Did you try desgining your product classes (Publisher, Format, Model, Districts)? Have you listed the processes & steps that are possible when assembling your data? For example: 1) define formats, assign formats to publishers 2) define formats, assign formats to model, assign model to publisher... Have you defined your builder interface to have a build() method for each distinct step? and a getResult() method for obtaining the built Publisher?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you understood correctly my "structure" except that (my bad, I didn't mention it) I know which Publisher (or District, or Model) the format is attached to with the data from the form. So the assembling order is Publisher->[District->[Model->]]Formats (I used the brackets to specify the "optionality" of the District and the Model). I finally developed an alternative Builder pattern that I will post in a few minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're talking about the Builder pattern.  The Builder pattern is for dealing with functions that accept many optional arguments.  You're probably thinking of the Factory pattern.

But to me it sounds like you want to apply a design pattern for the sake of having applied one.  I would think long and hard about what the problem really is before blindly applying someone else's solution.

EDIT: Okay, I think I misunderstood.  If you were certain these were the only possible combinations, you could create subclasses for each of them.  But it does sound like Builder is the most flexible solution.  Your builders should be methods that add the corresponding components to the Form, for example:

```
public class Form {
  ...
  public Form addModel() {
    this.models.push(new Model());
    return this;
  }
}
```

I don't know what you mean by whether your Products should be Format, Model, District and Publisher.  These don't sound like Products to me.  And I've no idea what Director or Client are, you haven't mentioned them anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I admit it's for the sake of having applied one, but I kinda have to : it is for an internship report and I want the application to be reusable / able to evolve if other possible associations appear.
But I don't understand why the Builder pattern doesn't match : isn't it supposed to create an object by assembling multiple parts (e.g., first the Publisher part, then the Districts contained in this publisher, then the Formats contained in these districts)?
And I don't see how the Factory pattern will apply given that there are no inheritance.

Comment: I don't have to build the Form from the data, I need to build the Publishers from the Form ;) and when I'm talking about Products, Director and Client, they are classes from the Builder UML class diagram. The final "Product" should be Publishers, but the Publisher class have optional attributes like District and Model. If the District attribute is instanciated (exists), the formats will be added to the District (which is itself included in the Publisher) instead of the Publisher. I will submit a solution in a few minutes that might solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally decide to implement an alternative Builder pattern (found here : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html) : using inner class to act as a builder in order to keep a valid state.

I remind you that the assembling order is : Publisher -> District -> Model -> Format (with District and Model optional)

Because my English is not that good, I prefer to post directly the code :

```
class Publisher{
// ATTRIBUTES
private $name;
private $districts;
private $models;
private $formats;

// GETTERS
...

// METHODES
private function __construct($builder) {
    $this->name = $builder->name;
    $this->districts = $builder->districts;
    $this->models = $builder->models;
    $this->formats = $builder->formats;
}


// BUILDER
public static class PublisherBuilder {
    private $name;
    private $districts; // catchment area
    private $models; // can be things like different car models
    private $formats;

    public function __construct($pName) {
        $this->name = $pName;
        $this->districts = array();
        $this->models = array();
        $this->formats = array();
    }

    public function setDistricts($pDistricts) { // the param is JSON-formatted      
        // If no Model declared by the user in the form
        // Loop over districts
            array_push($this->districts, new District.DistrictBuilder("name of the current district").setFormats("data about formats contained in the current district").build());

        // If several Models
        // Loop over districts
            array_push($this->districts, new District.DistrictBuilder("name of the current district").setModels("data about models contained in the current district").build());

        return $this;
    }

    public function setModels($pModels) {   // the param is JSON-formatted
        // Loop over models
            array_push($this->models, new Model.ModelBuilder("name of the current model").setFormats("data about formats contained in the current model").build());

        return $this;
    }

    public function setFormats($pFormats) { // the param is JSON-formatted
        // Loop over formats
            array_push($this->formats, new Format("data about the current format"));

        return $this;
    }

    public function build() {
        return new Publisher($this);
    }
} // end of inner class PublisherBuilder
```

} // end of Publisher class

And, of course, the District and Model class have the same structure with an builder inner class of their own (the Format class is a "normal" class).

The client will just have to loop over Publishers in the data from the form and call Publisher.PublisherBuilder("data about the current publisher).

With this solution, it seems that it removes some difficulties while maintaining the flexibility of the Builder pattern.

Don't hesitate to make any (constructive) comments on this implementation :)